# How to open out of python a ms access report with parameters

Tags: python, ms-access

so far i have this coding which works, only the where clause is not working. I can pass in the where clause whatever i want, it is not considered:

```
import win32com.client

a = win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.Application")
path = r'C:\Users\Egon\Documents\Kassenbuch_py\Pro Version\kassenbuch.accdb'
filename =r'C:\Users\Egon\Documents\Kassenbuch_py\Pro Version\pdf\kassenbuch.pdf'
# db = a.CloseCurrentDatabase()
db = a.OpenCurrentDatabase(path)
ReportName = 'kassenbuch'
try:
                

    StartDate = '#2021/06/13#'
    EndDate = '#2021/06/14#'

    acView = 'acViewPreview'
    where_cl = '[DATUM] BETWEEN ' + StartDate + ' AND ' + EndDate
    # where_cl = '"[EINNAHME] = 200"'

    a.DoCmd.OpenReport(ReportName, 2, where_cl ,3)
    # a.DoCmd.OpenReport(ReportName, 2, where_cl ,3)
    a.DoCmd.Save(3, ReportName)
    # a.visible = 1

    a.DoCmd.OutputTo(3, ReportName, r'PDF Format (*.pdf)', filename)

except Exception as e:
    
    QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Fehler', str(e), QMessageBox.Ok)

a.DoCmd.CloseDatabase
a.Quit()
a=None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's because you're passing a `WHERE` condition as the third argument, the filtername. Review the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.openreport).

If you pass an empty string there and pass your `WHERE` condition as the `WHERE` condition , it'll work:

```
a.DoCmd.OpenReport(ReportName, 2, '', where_cl ,3)
```

Note that the `DoCmd.Save` should not really be there, it does nothing since the design of the report wasn't changed.